# how to allow html tags in block helpers using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Below is the handle bars template which contains html elements

`{{#show}}
    <div class="intro">dummy</div>
    <div class="body">text</div>
 {{/show}}`

Following is the helper class

`Handlebars.registerHelper('show', function() {
  return true;
});`

The html elements should display only if **show** is true

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block helpers don't work quite like that. A block helper is passed an `options` object with two functions of interest inside it:

- `options.fn`: This represents the block.
- `options.inverse`: This represents the `{{else}}` block.

So your `show` helper shouldn't `return true`, it should `return options.fn()`. Something more like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('show', function(options) {
    if(some_condition)
        return options.fn(this);
    else
        return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Comment: its working ... thanks ... i got other solution also with {{unless}}